# JMeter Scripts - Clear a value in a Custom Property or Set it to null

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a JMeter script, and I need to clear a value of a Property (or set it to null). I tried the following:

```
props.put("MY_CUSTOM_PROPERTY", null);
```

This gives me a `NullPointerException`. Sample Stacktrace is given below.

```
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:224) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:950) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:549) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
```

Could someone help me clear the value in only one specific property?

Please see:

- I know I can use `props.clear()` to clear all properties to `null`.
- My JMeter version: 5.3
- Groovy version: 3.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything in order to set the value of non-existing property to `null`, it will be `null`:

[image]

You can use [props.remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) function to "clear" only one single property and leaving everything else intact like:

```
props.remove('MY_CUSTOM_PROPERTY')
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Answer (score 2):

You can't add null values, just use `remove`:

```
props.remove("MY_CUSTOM_PROPERTY");
```