# How to pass or set null value in variable to post request

Tags: jmeter

I'm posting HTTP request and JSR223 pre-processer to pass values like shown below,
Steps:

1. HTTP post request reading values from JSR223 pre-proccesser
2. Want to send null value for variable

**JSR223 pre-processer :**
vars.put("aptstatus","A")
vars.put("isccode",null)
I have used above way to pass value but in post request it is shown as

"status": "${aptstatus}",
"serviceCode": "${isccode}",

My requirement is to send null value in http post request.

Please help here how to set null value in variable.

Note: serviceCode is VARCHAR type

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you can use the props.remove function and feed it the value to make null such as props.remove('isccode').

Comment: Thanks for quick response but it's not working :(

Comment: Hmm take a look over at this post perhaps.
--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887796/jmeter-scripts-clear-a-value-in-a-custom-property-or-set-it-to-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor):

   ```
   vars.put("isccode", 'null')
   ```
2. In the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

   ```
   "status": "${aptstatus}", "serviceCode": ${isccode}
   ```

You will get:

```
"status": "A", "serviceCode": null
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)